# SciPy firwin2 has a low frequency error when designing arbitrary amplitude filter

Tags: python, audio, filtering, signal-processing

I've been trying to design an arbitrary amplitude FIR filter which has a specific attenuation for each frequency.

However I get an error at low frequency when comparing the results to my expected filter response as seen in the figure below. It doesn't change when raising the filter order.

The code is as follows:

```
import colorednoise as cn
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy
import scipy.signal as signal

# Generates a 3 seconds pink noise
x_raw=cn.powerlaw_psd_gaussian(1, 3*44100)
x_max=numpy.amax(numpy.abs(x_raw))
x=x_raw/x_max
fs=44100

# Vectors of the freq abnds and the corresponding attenuations
freq=numpy.array([0, 25.12, 31.62, 39.81, 50.12, 63.1, 79.43, 100, 125.89, 158.49, 199.53, 251.19, 316.23, 398.11, 501.19, 630.96, 794.33, 1000, 1258.93, 1584.89, 1995.25, 2511.89, 3162.28, 3981.07, 5011.87, 5012, 6309.57, 7943.28, 10000, 12589.25, 15848.93, 19952.62, 22050]);
att=numpy.array([-5.7,-5.7,-5.7,-5.7,-5.7,-2.8,-4.5,-3.9,-7.3,-11.2,-10.4,-11,-10.8,-10.1,-9.8,-7.9,-8.3,-7.7,-10.3,-12.8,-13.9,-15.1,-15.6,-17.3,-18.8,-18.8,-18.8,-18.8,-18.8,-18.8,-18.8,-18.8 ,-18.8])

gain=numpy.power(10,att/20)

b=signal.firwin2(8093,freq,gain,nyq=fs/2)

w,h=signal.freqz(b)
w,h=signal.freqz(b)
f=w*fs/(2*numpy.pi)

####### Plots the filter magnitude response ##########
pyplot.figure(1)
pyplot.plot(f,20*numpy.log10(numpy.abs(h)),label='Filter response')
pyplot.xscale('log')
pyplot.xlabel('Frequência [Hz]')
pyplot.ylabel('Magnitude [dB]')
pyplot.xlim((20,20000))
pyplot.plot(freq,att,label='Desired response')
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The length (or order) of a FIR filter has to be roughly proportional to the period of the lowest frequency you want to modify with a given response error or transition bandwidth.  For instance if you want the same accuracy of adjustment to a frequency 20X lower than a current mid-range frequency, then the FIR filter needs to be approximately 20X longer than one suitable for just that mid-range.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I have already tried to increase the filter order by x100 and it didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the missing argument worN in the scipy.signal.freqz function which you have used for visualization.

`w,h = signal.freqz(b, worN=np.geomspace(20, fs/2, 512))`